# Computed property that returns a sum of a property on each model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, computed-properties

I have a cart model then has items in it that looks something like this

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 1,
        "item_name":"Item 1",
        "item_price": 500
    },
    {
        "item_id": 2,
        "item_name": "Item 2",
        "item_price": 230
    },
    {
        "item_id": 3,
        "item_name": "Item 3",
        "item_price": 150
    }
]
```

I need to sum up the `item_price` property to be able to display it and then pass it along to ember data or an ajax call to complete a purchase.

Not sure if I'm just not understanding the agregate data thing with computeds but I am trying with this

```
totalDue: Ember.computed.sum('model.@each.item_price')
```

On the controller but it's returning 0

I am on ember `2.2.0`

Comment: `Ember.computed.sum` does something different: it just adds up the values in an array-valued property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this as a very clean one-liner:

```
totalDue: Ember.computed('model.@each.item_price', function() {
  return this.get('model').mapBy('item_price').reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
})
```

[Working Demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/7c0fab765d205a38c8dc)

Comment: Getting `this.get(...).mapBy is not a function` error in the console on that one.

Comment: If you put this - `console.log(this.get('model'))` - above the `return` statement, what does it output for you?

Comment: Sorry, forgot I switch the model to an RSVP hash so I needed to use `mode.items` to get at the items part of the model hash.

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
totalDue: Ember.computed('model.@each.item_price', function() {
  const model = this.get('model');
  if (!model) {
    return 0;
  }

  let sum = 0;
  model.forEach(item => sum += Ember.get(item, 'item_price'));
  return sum;
})
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/503b5d2ad6747b8c691e)

Comment: Getting `model.forEach is not a function`, also the model is being defined on the route in the model hook it just not using ember data or ajax call yet. Also I'm on ember `2.2.0`

Comment: Can you show me the `console.log(this.get('model'))` value in controller? So is `model` defined on controller or not? If not then you have to set `model` property in `setupController` hook in route before you use it.

Comment: Sorry your code worked, since I posted this I set up the route to return multiple models, so changing the line `this.get('model')` to `this.get('model.items')` worked

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      model: [
        {
          "item_id": 1,
          "item_name":"Item 1",
          "item_price": 500
        },
        {
          "item_id": 2,
          "item_name": "Item 2",
          "item_price": 230
        },
        {
          "item_id": 3,
          "item_name": "Item 3",
          "item_price": 150
        }
      ],

      array: Ember.computed.mapBy('model', 'item_price'),
      sum: Ember.computed.sum('array'),
    });
```